# How to re-render after renderEditCell in MUI Data Grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Editing the cell is working fine, but I have to reload the page to see the new value.
How can I re-render the cell without refreshing the page?

I already tried to update the rows whit apiRef.current.updateRows and also tried to force an update with apiRef.current.forceUpdate, but it doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea what I can also do?

```
{
    flex: 0.15,
    minWidth: 100,
    field: 'status',
    headerName: 'Status',
    renderEditCell: renderSelectEditInputCell,
    editable: true,
    renderCell: ({ row }) => {
      return (
        <CustomChip
          label={statusString[row.Status]}
        />
      )
    }
  },
```

```
function SelectEditInputCell(props) {
  const { id, value, field } = props
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext()
  // debugger;

  const handleChange = async event => {
    await axios
      .put(authConfig.defautlEndpoind + 'ABC/UpdateABCStatus', { Id: id, value: event.target.value })
      .then(async response => {
        apiRef.current.stopCellEditMode({ id, field })

        // apiRef.current.updateRows([{ id, field, value: event.target.value }])
        // apiRef.current.forceUpdate()
        // Router.reload(window.location.pathname) // force a page reload

      })
      .catch(error => {
        ...
      })

    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({ id, field, value: event.target.value })
  }

  return (
    <Select value={value} onChange={handleChange} native autoFocus>
      <option value={null} disabled selected>
        Status
      </option>
      <option value={0}>Option 1</option>
      <option value={1}>Option 2</option>
      <option value={2}>Option 3</option>
    </Select>
  )
}

SelectEditInputCell.propTypes = {
  /**
   * The column field of the cell that triggered the event.
   */
  field: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  /**
   * The grid row id.
   */
  id: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
  /**
   * The cell value.
   * If the column has `valueGetter`, use `params.row` to directly access the fields.
   */
  value: PropTypes.any
}

const renderSelectEditInputCell = params => {
  return <SelectEditInputCell {...params} />
}
```

edit:
some more things I tried so far:

```
apiRef.current.stopCellEditMode({ id, field })
apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({ id, field, value: event.target.value })
apiRef.current.refreshCell(id, field)
apiRef.current.forceUpdate([id]) // force update the specified row(s)
const updatedRow = { ...rows.find(row => row.id === id), [field]: event.target.value }
const updatedRows = rows.map(row => (row.id === id ? updatedRow : row))
setRows(updatedRows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom function on the `<Datagrid processRowUpdate={customFunction} />` which will call the API and update the row.

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#persistence

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).